# Get Lookup Source Pipeline not triggering for treelist

Tags: datasource

I have a dynamic source for a treelist field in my template.

[image]

In order to resolve the source location, I created a pipeline in `getLookupSourceItems` section.

The code snippet is shown below.

```
public class ResolveCustomSource
{

    public void Process(GetLookupSourceItemsArgs args)
    {
       Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)args.Item, "Item");
        if (this.SkipProcessor(args))
            return;

        //here i have some cutom processing to get the source

    }

    public virtual bool SkipProcessor(GetLookupSourceItemsArgs args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Source))
            return true;
       //check if datasource is present in the source of the field
    }

}
```

When I select the template containing the field in content editor or experience editor, the pipeline does not get triggered and the list is empty.

After reading some blogs, I decided to create a custom treelist inheriting from treelist. using this, the list gets populated on the content editor, but not on experience editor.

Comment: You'll need to add a custom button to the webedit in core db. Please see the following link https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781784396527/3/ch03lvl1sec33/creating-a-custom-experience-button-using-the-field-editor or this one: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3301/sitecore-mvc-edit-frame-for-treelist-field

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I created a field Editor Button and it did the trick.
Now the source of the treelist gets populated in the experience editor.